# Regex preg_match include whitespaces between div

Tags: php, html, regex, preg-match

Currently I'm working on a project where I need to get content from an HTML section and place it somewhere else.

We're using preg_match to find the content and put in an array. But we have a little struggle finding the right preg_match variables.

What we are using is this

```
preg_match('/<div class=\"sku\">(.*?)<\/div>/', $tmp, $match_sku);
```

But this is giving me an empty value in our array. What am I doing wrong?

[image: The content I want to extract]

Comment: You should use a parser for this. The `.` doesn't match new lines without the `s` modifier.

Comment: How do I put that one within the query? I'm quite new to regex :)

Comment: Hi Wouter,

You have white-space character around digits. White-space can be match with **\s**

Try this:

    preg_match('/<div class=\"sku\">\s?(.*)<\/div>/', $tmp, $match_sku);

Comment: Use a parser, not a regex.

Comment: Unfortunatly still not working Mike :(

Comment: `'~<div class="sku">(.*?)</div>~s'`. Only good if there are no nested `div` tags. Else use a DOM parser.